# UIScrollView Subviews not expanding to fill width (Autolayout)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm using the following code to constrain a view to the left and right anchors of a parent UIScrollView.

Despite the right anchor and the left anchor being set to the ScrollView's left and right anchors, the view does not expand to fill the scrollview.

Note: The gray background in this image is the UIScrollView's background, so I know that's properly constrained to its parent view.

Code:

```
self.wtfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.wtfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
self.wtfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.passwordField.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.rightAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UXXu.jpg

Edit:
The following code works correctly, but I would prefer to use the left+right anchor technique to specify the width, and not at a width constraint. Shouldn't that be possible?

```
self.wtfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.wtfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
self.wtfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.passwordField.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.widthAnchor, constant: -80.0).isActive = true //THE DIFFERENT ONE
self.wtfView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 040.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that the contentView of the UIScrollView still doesn't know that you want it to take up the width of it's parentView.

You can fix this by adding the following constraint in iOS11:

```
self.containerView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

This says "Hey, I want you to lock the content Width to the width of the superview.

Pre iOS 11 you can simply constrain a subview to both the parent view's left and right anchors AND the content view's left and right anchors.

Like so:

```
self.wtfView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
self.wtfView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
```

Much like, Aleksei's recommendation you are now constraining the width to a rigid value ( the width of the parent view ), and the scrollview will use that to decide the width of the scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

may be try to provide:

```
self.wtfView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: I’ll give this a shot in a bit, but shouldn’t a width constraint collide with the left and right anchors?

Comment: So, this works for me. If I keep the left constraint at 40, and add a width constraint with -80, it appears correct, but shouldn't providing a Left and Right anchor be sufficient?

Comment: thats what I also thought, but after long time debugging found that need to provide width